# Dojo equivalent of jquery ui position utility

Tags: jquery, dojo

In the jQuery UI you have the position utility where you can say for instance:

```
$("#div-id").position ({ my: "center center", at: "center center", of: "#content" });
```

This means: Place the center of my div with the id 'div-id' (x+y) at the center (x+y) of the div with the id 'content'.

Does a Dojo (1.7) utility exist that makes the same?
Thanks a lot
Wolfgang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
In Dojo there is a function called "dojo.position" plus "dojo.style", though not that convenient as the jquery one.

http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/position#introduction

Update:
In case you search for more "equivalents". I have just found a nice little "Rosetta Stone" for jQuery and Dojo: http://moresoda.co.uk/blog/article/dojo-and-jquery-side-by-side-dom-basics